# Typescript: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'BlendMode'

Tags: typescript

TypeScript question.
I need to pass a random parameter from this set:

```
letters.add("NORMAL");
letters.add("COLOR");
letters.add("LUMINOSITY");

 function getRandomItem(letters) {
    let items = Array.from(letters);
    return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
}
```

Letters definition:

```
const letters = new Set();

// Add Values to the Set
letters.add("NORMAL");
letters.add("DARKEN");
letters.add("MULTIPLY");
```

to a `rect.blendMode = getRandomItem(letters);`. So, it's expected to get something like rect.blendMode = "NORMAL";.

But I got an error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type `'BlendMode | "PASS_THROUGH"'`.  How can I pass a string with "" from my set to a `rect.blendMode =` ...?

Comment: Could you show the definition of `letters`?

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko yep, added.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `getRandomItem` function is not properly typed and TypeScript cannot defer what type it should return, so as a result it defaults to `unknown`.

Update your code to correctly type function parameters and return types as shown below:

```js
function getRandomItem(letters: Set<BlendMode>): BlendMode {
    let items = Array.from(letters);
    return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a typed array, unless you have a reason to use `Set`:

```
const allLetters = [
  "NORMAL",
  "DARKEN",
  "MULTIPLY",
  "COLOR",
  "LUMINOSITY",
] as const;

function getRandomItem(letters: typeof allLetters) {
  return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
}

const randomItem = getRandomItem(allLetters)
type TypeOfRandomItem = typeof randomItem
```

`TypeOfRandomItem` becomes

`type TypeOfRandomItem = "NORMAL" | "DARKEN" | "MULTIPLY" | "COLOR" | "LUMINOSITY"`